# Creating a bag file out of a image sequence

Tags: ros, python, rosbag, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a series of images and want to create a bag file out of them to use as input for the camera calibration.

Is it even necessary to create the bag for the calibration or is there another way to use the images?

If not, can a bag file be created from an image sequence? I guess using some python-fu it should be possible. Would that be a good idea?

UPDATE: Using the bag file for calibration seems not feasible as the standard calibration app insists on talking back to the camera. So to use that one will need to hack the script. The other possibility that might be working (testing atm) is a not documented script "tarfile_calibration.py" which can read a tar file containing the image sequence. Simply create a tar file with numbered images in format "left%d.png" and "right%d.png" and you're good to go:

```
rosrun camera_calibration tarfile_calibration.py MyImages.tar --square 0.108 --size 8x6
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11537/creating-a-bag-file-out-of-a-image-sequence/) by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ujur](https://answers.ros.org/users/36423/ujur/) on 2018-09-24**:
None of the above code worked

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-24**:
@ujur: your post is not an answer, so I converted it to a comment.

This is your second post that does not include any details whatsoever, so we cannot help you with it.

Please refrain from posting content like this, as it doesn't help others, and we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found this out myself. I haven't had the chance to test my bag files with the calibration yet, but they do play fine, so I'm assuming it should work. For anyone interested here's the script you can use to create a bag file from an image sequence (supports mono and stereo):

```
import time, sys, os
from ros import rosbag
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('sensor_msgs')
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

import ImageFile

def GetFilesFromDir(dir):
    '''Generates a list of files from the directory'''
    print( "Searching directory %s" % dir )
    all = []
    left_files = []
    right_files = []
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        for path, names, files in os.walk(dir):
            for f in files:
                if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg']:
                    if 'left' in f or 'left' in path:
                        left_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                    elif 'right' in f or 'right' in path:
                        right_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                    all.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
    return all, left_files, right_files

def CreateStereoBag(left_imgs, right_imgs, bagname):
    '''Creates a bag file containing stereo image pairs'''
    bag =rosbag.Bag(bagname, 'w')

    try:
        for i in range(len(left_imgs)):
            print("Adding %s" % left_imgs[i])
            fp_left = open( left_imgs[i], "r" )
            p_left = ImageFile.Parser()
        
            while 1:
                s = fp_left.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p_left.feed(s)
            
            im_left = p_left.close()
        
            fp_right = open( right_imgs[i], "r" )
            print("Adding %s" % right_imgs[i])
            p_right = ImageFile.Parser()
        
            while 1:
                s = fp_right.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p_right.feed(s)
            
            im_right = p_right.close()
        
            Stamp = roslib.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())
         
            Img_left = Image()
            Img_left.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img_left.width = im_left.size[0]
            Img_left.height = im_left.size[1]
            Img_left.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img_left.header.frame_id = "camera/left"
            Img_left_data = [pix for pixdata in im_left.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img_left.data = Img_left_data
            Img_right = Image()
            Img_right.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img_right.width = im_right.size[0]
            Img_right.height = im_right.size[1]
            Img_right.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img_right.header.frame_id = "camera/right"
            Img_right_data = [pix for pixdata in im_right.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img_right.data = Img_right_data
        
            bag.write('camera/left/image_raw', Img_left, Stamp)
            bag.write('camera/right/image_raw', Img_right, Stamp)
    finally:
        bag.close()

def CreateMonoBag(imgs):
    '''Creates a bag file with camera images'''
    bag =rosbag.Bag(bagname, 'w')

    try:
        for i in range(len(imgs)):
            print("Adding %s" % imgs[i])
            fp = open( imgs[i], "r" )
            p = ImageFile.Parser()
        
            while 1:
                s = fp.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p.feed(s)
            
            im = p.close()
        
            Stamp = roslib.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())
         
            Img = Image()
            Img.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img.width = im_left.size[0]
            Img.height = im_left.size[1]
            Img.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img.header.frame_id = "camera"
            Img_data = [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img_.data = Img_data
        
            bag.write('camera/image_raw', Img, Stamp)
    finally:
        bag.close()       


def CreateBag(args):
    '''Creates the actual bag file by successively adding images'''
    all_imgs, left_imgs, right_imgs = GetFilesFromDir(args[0])
    if len(all_imgs) <= 0:
        print("No images found in %s" % args[0])
        exit()
    
    if len(left_imgs) > 0 and len(right_imgs) > 0:
        # create bagfile with stereo camera image pairs
        CreateStereoBag(left_imgs, right_imgs, args[1])
    else:
        # create bagfile with mono camera image stream
        CreateMonoBag(all_imgs, args[1])        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len( sys.argv ) == 3:
        CreateBag( sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        print( "Usage: img2bag imagedir bagfilename")
```

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fins](https://answers.ros.org/users/2151/fins/) on 2013-04-03**:
Hi, I have an error running this script:
Img_data = [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Any idea? Thx.

**Comment by [Simon Leonard](https://answers.ros.org/users/13036/simon-leonard/) on 2014-03-09**:
Make sure your image is RGB and not mono.

**Comment by [Thalaiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23196/thalaiva/) on 2015-07-15**:
So just to clarify, I know this code was written for the purpose of calibration, but can I take a series of images taken from a prior video stream, and patch them together again so the final .bag file is a video?

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2016-01-09**:
I use this code with gray images via "python test.py imagesFolder test.bag" on ubuntu terminal.

```
 line 106, in CreateMonoBag
    Img_data = [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2016-01-09**:
Sorry, I am wrong. This code runs with rgb images. It works now!

**Comment by [flaver](https://answers.ros.org/users/63489/flaver/) on 2020-11-16**:
so how can i make a StereoBag using this script? Seems it automatically run the monoBag part

**Comment by [quantum guy 123](https://answers.ros.org/users/85226/quantum-guy-123/) on 2021-09-20**:
how do i add imu data to a rosbag?

**Comment by [quantum guy 123](https://answers.ros.org/users/85226/quantum-guy-123/) on 2021-09-20**:
what format does it need to be in?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CreateMonoBag had some problems, I made some modifications:

```
import time, sys, os
from ros import rosbag
import roslib
import rospy
roslib.load_manifest('sensor_msgs')
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

import ImageFile

def GetFilesFromDir(dir):
    '''Generates a list of files from the directory'''
    print( "Searching directory %s" % dir )
    all = []
    left_files = []
    right_files = []
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        for path, names, files in os.walk(dir):
            for f in files:
                if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.ppm']:
                    if 'left' in f or 'left' in path:
                        left_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                    elif 'right' in f or 'right' in path:
                        right_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                    all.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
    return all, left_files, right_files

def CreateStereoBag(left_imgs, right_imgs, bagname):
    '''Creates a bag file containing stereo image pairs'''
    bag =rosbag.Bag(bagname, 'w')

    try:
        for i in range(len(left_imgs)):
            print("Adding %s" % left_imgs[i])
            fp_left = open( left_imgs[i], "r" )
            p_left = ImageFile.Parser()

            while 1:
                s = fp_left.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p_left.feed(s)

            im_left = p_left.close()

            fp_right = open( right_imgs[i], "r" )
            print("Adding %s" % right_imgs[i])
            p_right = ImageFile.Parser()

            while 1:
                s = fp_right.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p_right.feed(s)

            im_right = p_right.close()

            Stamp = roslib.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())

            Img_left = Image()
            Img_left.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img_left.width = im_left.size[0]
            Img_left.height = im_left.size[1]
            Img_left.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img_left.header.frame_id = "camera/left"
            Img_left_data = [pix for pixdata in im_left.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img_left.data = Img_left_data
            Img_right = Image()
            Img_right.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img_right.width = im_right.size[0]
            Img_right.height = im_right.size[1]
            Img_right.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img_right.header.frame_id = "camera/right"
            Img_right_data = [pix for pixdata in im_right.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img_right.data = Img_right_data

            bag.write('camera/left/image_raw', Img_left, Stamp)
            bag.write('camera/right/image_raw', Img_right, Stamp)
    finally:
        bag.close()

def CreateMonoBag(imgs,bagname):
    '''Creates a bag file with camera images'''
    bag =rosbag.Bag(bagname, 'w')
   
    try:
        for i in range(len(imgs)):
            print("Adding %s" % imgs[i])
            fp = open( imgs[i], "r" )
            p = ImageFile.Parser()

            while 1:
                s = fp.read(1024)
                if not s:
                    break
                p.feed(s)

            im = p.close()

            Stamp = rospy.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())
            Img = Image()
            Img.header.stamp = Stamp
            Img.width = im.size[0]
            Img.height = im.size[1]
            Img.encoding = "rgb8"
            Img.header.frame_id = "camera"
            Img_data = [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
            Img.data = Img_data

            bag.write('camera/image_raw', Img, Stamp)
    finally:
        bag.close()       


def CreateBag(args):
    '''Creates the actual bag file by successively adding images'''
    all_imgs, left_imgs, right_imgs = GetFilesFromDir(args[0])
    if len(all_imgs) <= 0:
        print("No images found in %s" % args[0])
        exit()

    if len(left_imgs) > 0 and len(right_imgs) > 0:
        # create bagfile with stereo camera image pairs
        CreateStereoBag(left_imgs, right_imgs, args[1])
    else:
        # create bagfile with mono camera image stream
        CreateMonoBag(all_imgs, args[1])        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len( sys.argv ) == 3:
        CreateBag( sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        print( "Usage: img2bag imagedir bagfilename")
```

---

Originally posted by [Sahand](https://answers.ros.org/users/18881/sahand/) with karma: 11 on 2014-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [538amado](https://answers.ros.org/users/22912/538amado/) on 2015-06-24**:
I get this error with createMonoBag:

```
[ERROR] [1435157178.426668947]: Unable to convert 'bgr8' image to bgr8: 'Image is wrongly formed: step < width * byte_depth * num_channels  or  0 != 648 * 1 * 3'
```

The package runs. I get the error when trying to view the bag with image_view.
Any idea why?
Thx

**Comment by [Thalaiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23196/thalaiva/) on 2015-07-15**:
Are you using RGB images or mono?

**Comment by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) on 2016-02-16**:
I had the same issue with rgb8 images and fixed it by adding the line:

```
Img.step = Img.width * 3
```

where 3 is the number of channels. (in this case it's asking for a byte_depth of 1... I thought it should be byte_depth=8 but that doesn't work and I'm not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me, the line ("Stamp = roslib.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())") found a problem.

I saw in this page (http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.rostime.Time-class.html) an alternative: Stamp = rospy.Time.from_sec(time.time())

Good job!

---

Originally posted by [Tiago Giacomelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22027/tiago-giacomelli/) with karma: 11 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, here are some suggestions to improve:

In my case images are unordered.
To sort images in numerical order, a new function can be defined:

```
def CompSortFileNamesNr(f):
    g = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0]
    numbertext = ''.join(c for c in g if c.isdigit())
    return int(numbertext)
```

And in GetFilesFromDir, change line

```
            for f in files:
```

to

```
            for f in sorted(files, key=CompSortFileNamesNr):
```

In order to process a sequence of grey-level images, the code may be modified as follow:

Change "rgb8" encoding to "mono8",
and "[pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]" to "[pix for pixdata in **[**im.getdata()**]** for pix in pixdata]"

Bye

---

Originally posted by [julos](https://answers.ros.org/users/29438/julos/) with karma: 11 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-01-18**:
I am trying to save an image that has bitdepth of 2
I set
im.step = im.size[0] * 1
im.encoding = "mono16"
but i'm getting an error from  msg.serialize(self._buffer) in bag.py:
genpy.message.SerializationError: field data[] exceeds specified width [uint8] field_val 1574 maxval 256